# mailed by php how to use it?

Tags: php

How can i use the mail by header in php?

This is what i use now:

```
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n

$headers = "From: test@gmail.com\r\nReply-To:test@gmail.com";

//send the email
$to = "test@gmail.com";

 $subject = "This is a subject";

 $body = "Hi there!";

 if (mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers)) 
{

echo("\nMessages successfully sent!");

  } else {

   echo("\nMessages delivery failed...");
  }
```

I get this on my gmail when i click on show details:

from    test@gmail.com
reply-to    testreply@gmail.com
to  test@gmail.com
date    Sat, May 14, 2011 at 12:06 AM
subject stefanos neofitidis! You commented on your poem:Tree present
mailed-by   ip-1-1-1-1.ip.secureserver.net

i do not want to the ip-1-1-1-1.ip.secureserver.net to show up to the users...this is what i am trying to change!

Comment: And what happens when you run it? Don't say "it doesn't work." Please give details (error/warning messages, logs).

Comment: This might be an overkill: http://llihp.blogspot.com/2011/05/php-mail-class.html

Comment: from test@gmail.com
reply-to testreply@gmail.com
to test@gmail.com
date Sat, May 14, 2011 at 12:06 AM
subject stefanos neofitidis! You commented on your poem:Tree present
mailed-by ip-1-1-1-1.ip.secureserver.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is add a fifth parameter in your mail() function, which needs to use the "-f" sendmail option.

For example:

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-fsender@domain.com");
```

Sending a message with that last parameter will change the envelope sender to "sender@domain.com".  Most of the time, email providers like gmail won't even show that address if it is set by hand(which is what you want, I'm assuming).

See https://www.php.net/function.mail for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the X-Mailer?

```
$headers = "From: test@gmail.com\r\nReply-To:test@gmail.com\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

Comment: show details in gmail shows the IP of the server under mailed by. I do not want the ip to be visible under mailed by header.

Comment: @stefanosn, it must be.  There isn't anything you *should* do about this.  There may be things you *can*, but *don't*.

Comment: The information in "mailed by" gmail will get from the Received-headers. Those headers will be send by the mailserver, I don't think that there is a PHP-way to modify those headers.